# WPF .net 3.5 unicode bug

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unicode

WPF controls won't display sinhala unicode characters properly. However this problems is only with .net 3.5, while .net 4.0 and 4.5 seem to work flawless.

[image]

Any suggestions on a fix, I have to use .net 3.5?

Comment: sounds pretty easy to me : use the framework that contains the fix

Comment: True, but then all the clients will have to install .net 4.0 as well right? where as .net 3.5 comes with windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .NET version that supports Unicode version with correct Sinhala support. Unicode before Unicode 5.0 doesn't support Sinhala well.

Use .NET 4.0 and above to support at least Unicode 5.1, although not yet fully supported in Windows 7. Windows 7 SP1 and Windows 8 provides additional supports for Unicode 5.1.

Visit this link for more information: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx